# how to remove a row which has empty column in a dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have to remove entire row with the column, which has no value my dataframe looks like

```
Name   place    phonenum

mike   china     12344
       ireland    897654
suzzi  japan      09876
chang  china      897654
       Australia  897654
       india      876543
```

required output should be

```
Name   place    phonenum

mike   china     12344
suzzi  japan      09876
chang  china      897654
```

I have used `df1=df[df.Name  == '']`
I got output

```
  Name   place    phonenum
```

Please help me

Comment: What is `print(df.index)` ?

Answer (score 10):

If `Name` is column:

```
print (df.columns)
Index(['Name', 'place', 'phonenum'], dtype='object')
```

Need change `==` to `!=` for not equal if missing values are empty strings:

```
print (df)
    Name      place  phonenum
0   mike      china     12344
1           ireland    897654
2  suzzi      japan      9876
3  chang      china    897654
4         Australia    897654
5             india    876543

df1 = df[df.Name != '']
print (df1)
    Name  place  phonenum
0   mike  china     12344
2  suzzi  japan      9876
3  chang  china    897654
```

If in first columns are `NaN`s use [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) with specify column for check:

```
print (df)
    Name      place  phonenum
0   mike      china     12344
1    NaN    ireland    897654
2  suzzi      japan      9876
3  chang      china    897654
4    NaN  Australia    897654
5    NaN      india    876543

df1 = df.dropna(subset=['Name'])
print (df1)
    Name  place  phonenum
0   mike  china     12344
2  suzzi  japan      9876
3  chang  china    897654
```

Comment: I used it but rows with empty column is not removed

Comment: Ok, what about `df1 = df.dropna(subset=['Name'])` ?

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had a bunch of fields with dates, strings, and one column for values (also called "Value"). I tried all suggestions above, but what actually worked was to drop NA records for the "Value" field.

`df = df.dropna(subset=['Value'])`

Answer (score 3):

DataFrame dropna() method will drop entire row if any value in the row is missing.

```
df1 = df.dropna()
```

Comment: by using this all columns which are empty entire row is deleting but i want to delete only Name column empty , then remove that itself.