# How to remove all those rows from a csv file that are empty of a specific column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

[image: Example CSV file]

In the following csv I want to remove all rows that are empty with respect to column **'Age'** only (i.e. row 4 & 5 to be removed of entire file)

I tried

```
df['Age'].dropna(how ='any')
```

But this isn't the solution.

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). [Why should I not upload images of ... when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Does - [Drop rows containing empty cells from a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314033/drop-rows-containing-empty-cells-from-a-pandas-dataframe)  - answer your question?

Comment: [how to remove a row which has empty column in a dataframe using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51374068/how-to-remove-a-row-which-has-empty-column-in-a-dataframe-using-pandas)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dropna` with the `subset` argument:

`df.dropna(subset=['Age'], how='any')`